# NativeBase tabs unable to customise borderBottomColor

Tags: react-native, tabs, native-base

I have few tabs defined as below:

```
<Tabs renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTab />}>
      <Tab heading="Tab1" tabStyle={styles.tabStyling} activeTabStyle={styles.activeTabStyle} textStyle={styles.tabTextStyle} activeTextStyle={styles.activeTabTextStyle} />
      <Tab heading="Tab2" tabStyle={styles.tabStyling} activeTabStyle={styles.activeTabStyle} textStyle={styles.tabTextStyle} activeTextStyle={styles.activeTabTextStyle} />
      <Tab heading="Tab3" tabStyle={styles.tabStyling} activeTabStyle={styles.activeTabStyle} textStyle={styles.tabTextStyle} activeTextStyle={styles.activeTabTextStyle} />
      <Tab heading="Tab4" tabStyle={styles.tabStyling} activeTabStyle={styles.activeTabStyle} textStyle={styles.tabTextStyle} activeTextStyle={styles.activeTabTextStyle} />
      <Tab heading="Tab5" tabStyle={styles.tabStyling} activeTabStyle={styles.activeTabStyle} textStyle={styles.tabTextStyle} activeTextStyle={styles.activeTabTextStyle} />
</Tabs>
```

With below style:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tabStyling: {
    backgroundColor: '#37b372'
  },
  activeTabStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#37b372',
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderBottomColor: 'red'
  },
  tabTextStyle: {
    color: 'black'
  },
  activeTabTextStyle: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 20
  }
});
```

on `activeTabStyle`, I've defined `borderBottomColor: 'red'` but it still giving me default blue color instead

[image]

And below is the interface from `NativeBase`

```
interface Tab {
  heading: React.ReactElement<TabHeading> | string;
  tabStyle?:ReactNative.ViewStyle | Array<ReactNative.ViewStyle>;
  activeTabStyle?: ReactNative.ViewStyle | Array<ReactNative.ViewStyle>;
  textStyle?: ReactNative.TextStyle;
  activeTextStyle?: ReactNative.TextStyle;
}
```

So `activeTabStyle` should be nothing more than just basic `ReactNative.ViewStyle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to use `tabBarUnderlineStyle` as mentioned [here](http://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#tabs-def-headref), since it is a property of `Tabs` and not `Tab`.

For example

```
<Tabs tabBarUnderlineStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'YOUR_SAMPLE_COLOR' }} renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTab /> }>
  {... // Rest of the data}                   
</Tabs>
```

*Also another thing to note is your style is being applied but it is hidden below the default border.*
To notice it, you can add

```
 activeTabStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#37b372',
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderBottomColor: 'red',
    borderBottomWidth: 10
  },
```